# Why Not Get Channel Info From HTTP Header At The Beginning When Using WebSocket

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

recently I take `"github.com/gorilla/websocket"` as the underlying websocket implementation and gin web framework for my project.

I googled many examples and found many people used handshakes for their websocket channels, e.g. they let the client register the channel after the connection is upgraded to web socket and then got the client's identity information from the registration request.

My question is:
from the server side, the server is able to get registration information, such as userId, userName etc., from HTTP Header (before the connection is upgraded to websocket), the only thing to do is letting the client put the identity into into HTTP Headers. Why people don't do it this way, and instead they use the handshake which is much more troublesome?

**update**
The client is able to open many channels, so we have to register every channel to track their usage. And because we will use the channel to send multiple types of messages and they are distingushed by cmd field in the body, so though we are able to get id information from headers, we still need to get channel usage information from websocket data for all the other commucations except the initial registration. To keep constistency between all messages, we register the channel by websocket data other than http header. Is it that reason??

Comment: The examples may have requirements that force sending the authentication information in a websocket message. It is common to authenticate using cookies before upgrade.